# how to split the list in json dictionary and hit the maps using parallel in aws step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

my parallel state will get the following input:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "payload": [
    {
      "Status": "Requested (by user)",
      "Action": "",
      "Item_Id": "1861",
      "File_name": ""
    },
    {
      "Status": "Requested (by user)",
      "Action": "",
      "Item_Id": "1862",
      "File_name": ""
    },
    //so on
    ]
}
```

from parallel I have two maps, one map should get statuscode and payload[0:40] as input and another should get statuscode and payload[40:80] as input.

I tried to filter input with input path, where I gave $.payload[0:40], for this I got:

```
Unable to apply step "payload" to input [
{"Status":"Requested (by user)","Action":"","Item_Id":"1861","File_name":""},...
]
```

the length of list seems to be 40.

I also tried changing the parameter values, tried to hardcode, nothing seems to be working.

I am new to this, correct me where I am going wrong.

```
the code I am using:

`{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
  "States": {
    "Lambda Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:function name"
      },
      "Next": "Choice",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "SNS Publish",
          "ResultPath": "$.ErrorMessage"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.payload",
          "NumericEquals": 0,
          "Next": "Success (1)"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.payload",
          "NumericGreaterThan": 0,
          "Next": "ParallelProcessing"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "ParallelProcessing"
    },
    "ParallelProcessing": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Map",
          "States": {
            "Map": {
              "Type": "Map",
              "ItemProcessor": {
                "ProcessorConfig": {
                  "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
                  "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
                },
                "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke (1)",
                "States": {
                  "Lambda Invoke (1)": {
                    "Type": "Task",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
                    "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
                    "Parameters": {
                      "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:functionname",
                      "Payload.$": "$"
                    },
                    "Retry": [
                      {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                          "Lambda.ServiceException",
                          "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                          "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                          "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                        ],
                        "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                        "MaxAttempts": 3,
                        "BackoffRate": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "Catch": [
                      {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                          "States.ALL"
                        ],
                        "Next": "SNS Publish (1)",
                        "ResultPath": "$.ErrorMessage"
                      }
                    ],
                    "Next": "Choice (1)"
                    .....so on 
                  },
              "Label": "Map",
              "MaxConcurrency": 40,
              "ItemsPath": "$.payload",
              "ToleratedFailurePercentage": 97.5,
              "ToleratedFailureCount": 39,
              "End": true,
              "InputPath": "$.payload[0:40]"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Wait",
          "States": {
            "Wait": {
              "Type": "Wait",
              "Seconds": 2,
              "Next": "new_state_1"
            },
            "new_state_1": {
              "Type": "Map",
              "ItemProcessor": {
                "ProcessorConfig": {
                  "Mode": "DISTRIBUTED",
                  "ExecutionType": "STANDARD"
                },
                "StartAt": "lambda2",
                "States": {
                  "lambda2": {
                    "Type": "Task",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
                    "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
                    "Parameters": {
                      "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:funcname",
                      "Payload.$": "$"
                    },
                    "Retry": [
                      {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                          "Lambda.ServiceException",
                          "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                          "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                          "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                        ],
                        "IntervalSeconds": 1,
                        "MaxAttempts": 3,
                        "BackoffRate": 2
                      }
                    ],
                    "Catch": [
                      {
                        "ErrorEquals": [
                          "States.ALL"
                        ],
                        "Next": "SNS Publish (6)",
                        "ResultPath": "$.ErrorMessage"
                      }
                    ],
                    "Next": "check_errors_1"
              },
              "Label": "new_state_1",
              "MaxConcurrency": 40,
              "ItemsPath": "$.payload",
              "End": true,
              "ToleratedFailurePercentage": 97.5,
              "ToleratedFailureCount": 39,
              "InputPath": "$.payload[40:80]"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
```

}`